# Diagonal entries and determinant of positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

Given a $3x3$ symmetric, positive matrix $\lambda |x|^2 \leq x^TAx \leq \Lambda |x|^2$, let us denote $a_{11}$, $a_{22}$ and $a_{33}$ to be the diagonal elements. Furthermore, let us denote the values $A_{12} = det \left|\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{array}\right|$, $A_{13} = det \left|\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} \end{array}\right|$. Analogously, let us denote $A_{21}= A_{12}$, $A_{23} = det \left|\begin{array}{cc} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{array}\right|$ and $A_{31} = A_{13}$ and $A_{32} = A_{23}$.

In particular, $A_{ij}$ can be viewed as the determinant of the $2x2$ principal submatrix containing $a_{ii}$ and $a_{jj}$.

Is it true that one can rearrange the matrix to ensure $a_{11}^2 \leq A_{12}$ and $a_{11}^2 \leq A_{13}$ holds?

If $A$ is a diagonal matrix, then it is easy to see that this is indeed true by taking the diagonal entries in increasing order, but I am unable to prove this for general symmetric matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by “rearrange the matrix”? Permute the rows and columns by the same permutation?

Comment: Or, in other words, why isn't $\begin{bmatrix} 3&1&1\\1&3&1\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$ a counterexample?